# Auth::login() is not working in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

`Auth::login()` is not working. Before doing this project I did another one then it was worked.
Here is User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    use HasFactory;
}
```

Here is my controller for login:

```
function loggedIn(Request $request){
       echo $name = $request['name'];
        $password = $request['password'];
        $user = User::where([
            ["name", $name],
            ["password", $password],
        ])->get()->first();

        if ($user != ''){
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect()->route('welcome');

        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with(['error'=>'Ismingiz tasdiqlanmadi!']);
        }

    }
```

Controller redirecting welcome route but welcome route again redirecting it to the login page.
Route welcome has middleware auth:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome')->middleware('auth');
```

If you have a solution, please inform me!

Comment: try to create a smaller example for yourself and see where things start to no longer work. I would suggest stop echo-ing like in `loggedIn` because this disrupts some functions in Laravel. for example bacause: >Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: "X is not working." – Please be more specific (error messages, under what circumstances)?

Comment: Thank you online Thomas you helped a lot! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [onlie Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754599/online-thomas) wrote on comment:

> try to create a smaller example for yourself and see where things
> start to no longer work. I would suggest stop echo-ing like in
> loggedIn because this disrupts some functions in Laravel. for example
> bacause: >Remember that header() must be called before any actual
> output is sent

My mistake, I have wrote `echo`, before `header()` function;

Answer (score 0):

For me, my error was that I put the routes of auth redirect and auth callback inside the `api.php` file, **putting these on `web.php` worked**!

---

In the docs [Laravel Socialite | Authentication & Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#authentication-and-storage) Laravel proposes two routes, `/auth/redirect` and `/auth/callback`, but it doesn't specify in which file put those routes, I tried first with `api.php`, but that didn't work. After some time I decided to put the 2 routes inside the `web.php`, which worked.